# Logic and Conditional Law

Tags: logic

I'm working through some logic problems and just encountered one which doesn't seem to be logical and I would really appreciate your help helping me with it.

The statement $$\ a \notin \text{A \ B} $$ is equivalent to $$\ \lnot(a \in A  \land a \notin B)$$ which is the definition of A\B, which is also equivalent to $$\ a \notin A \lor a \in B$$  which is DeMorgan'law, which again can be transformed into $$\ a \in A \to a \in B $$

I  am able to follow everything until the last reexpression which I believe means "If a belongs to set A then a also belongs to set B".
But the previous statement means "a does not belong to set A or a  belongs to B"  which simply means a belongs to set B,  right?

The last statement seems to be correct based on the conditional law, but somehow i can't logically follow it.

Would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot follow your not being able to follow. Let $A$ be the set of philosophers and $B$ the set of living persons. Then $A\setminus B$ is the set of non-living (aka. dead) philosphers. So the original statement $a\notin A\setminus B$ is "$a$ is not a dead philosopher". So if the $a$ you have in mind is a philosopher, they have to be alive

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think his issue might be that he is presuming that the usage of the $\text{A \ B}$ notation requires $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you say it that way i can follow it. But if we simply look at the last two statements  ∉∨∈ and ∈→∈, How can I conclude from the first "a doesnt belong to A or a belongs to B" to "if a belongs to A then a belongs to B"?

Comment: Because $\lnot P \lor Q$ is [equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) $P \to Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $A = \{2,~ 3,~ 4\}$ and $B = \{10,~11,~12\}$ and $a = 6$ ?

It might be that your issue is that you are assuming $A \text{ \\ } B$ is only defined when $B \subseteq A$.  That may be true in common language but in conventional mathematics there is no subset requirement.

Answer (score 2):

A long time later; and attempt to be useful here. Only my thoughts:

> But the previous statement means "a does not belong to set A or a belongs to B" which simply means a belongs to set B, right?

I think that the 'previous statement' definitely tells us:
'That if a belongs to A it must also belong to B.'

This is because the statement conveys that any time a is not not A (i.e. is A) must coincide with a time that it is B, if it is conforming to the statement and therefore in our group.

So this statement rules out a being simultaneously A and not B.

> which simply means a belongs to set B, right?

No, not correct. It could belong to some C which is exclusive of both sets A and B.

(In addition, there is a danger that you are imagining that 'simply means a belongs to set B' means it is all items in B, which I want to clarify is not being asserted either. We are just setting conditions around a but not determining positively all instances of it.)