# How to restructure the logic of $a \notin A$ \ $B$ into $a \in A \implies a \in B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

I'm working through Velleman's 'How to Prove It' and am trying to understand a logical transposition of a proof's goal.

The proof to answer is:
"Suppose $A \cap C \subseteq B$ and $a \in C$. Prove $a \notin A$ \ $B$."

The book describes restructuring the goal to a positive statement and shows that:

$a \notin A$ \ $B$ is equivalent to $a \in A \implies a \in B$.

So far the steps I have taken are expressing $a \notin A$ \ $B$ as $\neg (a \in A \land a \notin B)$, so then becoming $a \notin A \lor a \in B$ using De Morgan's law. However from here the book jumps to $a \in A \implies a \in B$, referencing the Conditional law, but I can't understand how $a$ can now be an element of A and still hold true that $a \in B$. Any insight into the logic behind this step would be greatly appreciated as I'm pretty new to these concepts

Comment: Unfortunately I already reached that stage as shown

Comment: Ok, what about $\neg (p \land q) \Leftrightarrow (\neg p \lor \neg q )$?

Comment: " I can't understand how $a$
 can now be an element of $A$ and still hold true that $a \in B$ " via Assumption. Suppose $a \in C$ and now also $a \in A$ therefore $a \in A \cap C$ and thus $a \in B$

Comment: That makes sense, but since the previous statement showed $a \notin A \lor a \in B$, how can it then be true that if $a \in A$ then $a \in B$

Comment: One and, hope, last step: $(\neg p \lor  q)\Leftrightarrow (p \Rightarrow q)$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3869488/1093356)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You showed that $a \notin A$\ $B$ is equivalent to $a \notin A \lor a \in B$. I'll show you why your statement is equivalent to $a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$.
These statements are equivalent when their logical values coincide.
Suppose $a \notin A \lor a \in B$ is true then either $a \notin A$ is true, then
$a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$ is also true, or $a \in B$ is true, then
$a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$ is also true.
Now suppose $a \notin A \lor a \in B$ is false. Than $a \notin A$ and $a \in B$ are false which means $a \in A \land a \notin B$. This means $a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$ is false.
Therefore from $a \notin A \lor a \in B$ follows $a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$.
If you do the other direction analog you can see that they are indeed equivalent.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you for taking the time to explain it so thoroughly for me